# Horizontal scrollbars issue

Tags: html, css

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Hasn't helped also

http://codepen.io/samducker/pen/YpQejY

Can't for the life of me find out why I have a tiny bit of white space on the right. Have tried removing stylesheets one by one and going through margin and padding and have still had no luck.

Please help me!

Comment: overflow-x: hidden; on body will hide the white space, but not solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `container-fluid` class to the section with `class="header"`. See the following piece of code:

```
<section class="header container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://thehedonistproject.com/launch/img/team.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The problem is that bootstrap require that each element with class `row` has to be contained inside an element that have a `container` or `container-fluid` class to assign the right margins and paddings.

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you. Can you explain why that fixed it, so I know when to use this in future.

Comment: @Sam Ducker Adding `container` or `container-fluid` class change how style will be applied to elements that have `row` class. Since `container-fluid` class make the element to use full width page, it remove margins on child row element. If you wish to get more information you can check the following page: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

Or just get rid of the annoying margin on .row

```
.row {
  margin:0 !important;
}
```